# Website does not reflect changes on live after uploading files via FTP

Tags: uploads, updates, ftp, post-content

I have a Wordpress site that is already published on a domain. As I wanted to update the content of some pages, I edited the local version of my website on localhost and then uploaded the files using an FTP client. However, the changes do not appear on the live site. I cleared the cache of my browser and also emptied all caches of my wordpress site using a plugin. Still no content updates showing on the website.

Comment: what did you transferred? just files or database or both? you have to update the database as well incase not done. better solution is to edit in the live website itself as you will have revisions just incase you want to go back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between Wordpress files you upload on your **FTP**, and Wordpress "content" that is stored in your **database**.

For your content to be updated, **you have to migrate your Wordpress database online**.

**Resources:**

- This link explains how you can migrate your Wordpress website entirely https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/
- For example, has stated by @WebElaine, you can use database migration plugins such as this one among others https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

---

*Also, as said in the comments, you could also copy paste your content from localhost to your live website. In order for the whole thing to be easier, try using the "preview" functionality in your editor instead of updating your localhost website.*

Comment: Do you mean by migrating your Wordpress database online replacing the current database on cpanel by the new one, i.e. an export of the local database with all the last challenges?

Comment: Basically, yes, but be sure to use a database migration plugin if you go that route. WordPress stores serialized data and the whole site can break if you just try to overwrite the database. Unless you've edited a ton of pages, it may be easier to simply copy and paste from your local editor into the live site editor.

Comment: @Has, be sure to save your old database before doing anything. I will edit my answer with ressources to help you achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare both files code, If your both online and local code matches that mean you have some other issue. If you have CDN on your sever then you have to refresh `CDN-links` because php code doesn't make cache only `.css` and `.js` does.